# Github Action Labeler does not match **/*

Tags: label, github-actions, pull-request

I am using this Github Action [Labeler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/labeler) to match all `.md` markdown files changed in any place in the repository, regardless of the path.
I followed the documentation, even trying few different configurations, but I do not manage to make it work. I must be doing some stupid mistakes, but I cannot figure it out.
I have created [this repo](https://github.com/alebaffa/github-actions-tests) to test my changes.

I have `.github/labeler.yml` with this:

```bash
documentation:
- '**/*.md' # I also tried with /**/*.md but does not work either
```

and `.github/workflows/labeler.yml` with this:

```bash
name: "Labeler"
on:
- pull_request_target # also tried - pull_request with types [opened]

jobs:
  pr-labeler:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/labeler@v4.1.0
      with:
        sync-labels: true
```

But when I make a PR that contains some .md files, it does not label the PR.

Any one can spot the mistake I am making?

Comment: It looks like nothing triggers any workflow whatsoever. Are actions enabled for the repo?

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminW, i just noticed that the workflows subfolder was actually named .workflows...so i fixed that and the Action starts and successfully completes, but still no documentation label is applied (as configured in the .github/labeler.yml file).

Comment: Try `**/*.md` instead of `/**/*.md`.

Comment: I saw your bug issue, and I agree, it seems to be a bug. I was able to get the label applied when using v4.0.4, the previous release, though then you can't use the `dot` feature.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use 4.0.4 for now.